# Execution Level Setup & Teardown with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I understand there's `Test Setup` which will get executed before every test case and `Suite Setup` which will get executed before every suite (i.e. each .robot file).

However, I'm trying to do Setup and Teardown of the command level which is Setup once I run the `robot` command and when all test suites have ran, run Teardown.

Tried with having `__init__.robot` file in my scenario directory but they didn't get called at all.

```
*** Settings ***

Resource  ../_common/keywords.robot

Suite Setup  Prepare Browser
Suite Teardown  Close Browser
```

I want to be able to launch the browser before any test is started and then close browser only after all tests are completed.

For example, `robot 1.robot 2.robot` should:

1. Open browser
2. Run `1.robot` test suite
3. Run `2.robot` test suite
4. Close browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by having "special" suites just for that, and call them first and last in a run. With the SeleniumLibrary having a global scope, the browser initialized in the first one should be accessible for all follow-up suites in the same run.

E.g. the suite "Startup.robot" will open the browser, and "Closing.robot" will close it, and any in between will use it:

```
robot Startup.robot 1.robot 2.robot Closing.robot
```

When you pass a directory for execution, the framework takes the .robot files in it in alphabetical order, so you can name those special suites "0000_Startup.robot" and "zzzz_Closing.robot" for them to be ran in the corresponding order (that's if you use only ascii/latin file names).

---

And yep, the initialization files are not used to run something before the other suites - they are there to set default values for those other suites, which can be overridden downstream. [See their description in the documentation.](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files)

Comment: Was hoping for a more integrated way instead but I guess it's just not supported since I can't find anything like it in the documentation and initialization file was the closest thing I could find.

Comment: What I myself do is having custom keywords for opening and closing the browser, treating it as a singleton - don't recreate if it's present, don't really close it except a special condition. But that's much more involving solution than the case you present here - for which a simple naming scheme is much easier to implement.

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work if and when there is no failure in the connection to the browser. When that happens a new browser should be opened.

Comment: @TodorMinakov That makes perfect sense. I suppose this answer was aimed to directly answer the question I've had. Thanks.